# Always get 404 though I don't see anything wrong in my hello-world Spring mvc project

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, tomcat9

I have setup a very simple Spring MVC hello-world type of project. But when I run it on tomcat, I always get 404. I spent hours on it I can't figure out where I did wrongly.

I am using Spring Tool Suite 4 & tomcat v9.

My web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>fitServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My servlet-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

   <mvc:annotation-driven/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.xi.controller"/>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
   p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" 
   p:suffix=".jsp"/>

</beans>
```

My controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String sayHello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World!");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

My hello.jsp located under /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Fit tracking</title>
</head>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<body>
<h1>${greeting}</h1><br>
<strong>Current Time is</strong>: <%=new Date() %>

</body>
</html>
```

The folder structure of WEB-INF:

[image]

For example, after I deployed to tomcat server, I type URL on browser

http://localhost:8080/FitTracker/greeting.html

I get this page:
[image]

I can't see why. I am supposed to see the JSP page...

Comment: What happens when you use `@RequestMapping("/greeting.html")`? Is your controller in the com.xi.controller package? Is it created? Is it called?

Comment: it doesn't directly answer your question, but I would like to recommend to use Spring Boot as a foundation for your projects moving forward. There is a good integration for those projects in Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse and you can easily start them right away without deploying them to a local Tomcat server first. It makes development a lot easier. If you still want to go ahead with your non-Boot project and deploy that to a local Tomcat, feel free to attach the sample project and we can have a look at what might be going wrong here.

Answer (score -1):

You have not defined greeting.html anywhere

Comment: I defined in url-pattern of web.xml for the `*.html` suffix and in controller code defined `@RequestMapping("/greeting")

Comment: The request mapping you defined is the path param and not html. You need to have the url in form of

Comment: How to define the mapping then if mine is wrong? I don't think I need to put the whole  `localhost:8080/FitTracker/greeting ` in my web.xml. Could you please provide a clear answer?

Comment: The url i mentioned above should be used in browser to navigate

Comment: I don't understand your answer to be honest, since I am using the correct url in browser like you answered here. It is mentioned in my question.